# rubyonrails.org tutorial shows wrong View in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed the directions up to step 5. There was a View folder called Layouts with a file called application.html.erb that was automatically created but the tutorial hasn't mentioned it at all. I don't know if I'm supposed to delete it or leave it alone. I created a View that appears in Explorer as a Welcome folder with index.html.erb as the file, edited the file to show some HTML and edited routes.rb so they root would point to this welcome page following exact steps in section 4.3 Setting the Application Home Page.

Viewing the project in browser just pulled up an error message that something is wrong with the application.html.erb that I hadn't even touched. I temporarily replaced contents with just a this shouldn't be here  and refreshed, sure enough "this shouldn't be here" is what appears in my browser at localhost:3000 instead of the contents of index.html.erb

Went back to command prompt to see if changing the route had worked and I would assume it did:

```
C:\Users\Susan\ruby_projects\blog>rake routes
   Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
     welcome_index GET  /welcome/index(.:format) welcome#index
     root          GET  /                        welcome#index
```

Why is it showing this other file instead of mine when I open it in the browser if the routes say to go to mine?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snippet you tried to use. It would help people answering your question greatly! Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

`layouts/application.html.erb` is a default file which is loaded on every page of your rails application, unless you specify not to, it is used for having a same pattern through out your website, and make your code DRY.  You can learn more here [Layouts & Rendering](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)